# How to preserve access_token in cypress 12.0.3

Tags: automation, cypress, session-cookies

`As we all know that we cannot open a new tab  while performing tests using cypress, for that purpose I am preserving a access_token in before() function so that we can open that url in same tab.

In cypress 10.X we are suing following code and it is working fine.

```
`` before(function () {
        // cy.viewport(1024, 768)
         cy.Cookies.defaults({
            preserve :"access_token"
         })
       })``
```

but after update to cypress 12.0.3 code isn't migrated and it stop working for  cy.cookies.defaults are deprecated.

I have tried below code but it still doesn't working

```
`before(function () {
        cy.viewport(1024, 768)
        Cypress.Cookies.debug({
           preserve: "access_token"
        })
    })`
```

`